# PostgreSQL and days that don't exist?

Tags: postgresql, update

While updating data in my table i am getting below error.

```
 date/time field value out of range: "2017-2-29"
```

I want to skip this error and want update statement to continue further.

How can we do this with update statement.

Comment: By not trying to store an invalid date?

Comment: Are you trying to find out if the `UPDATE` statement would generate other errors? In a dev/test environment, change the date to something valid (or NULL, if all else fails), or modify the statement not to update that column. However, the simplest solution is to figure out how to fix that bad data (either in the data you're bringing in, or in the update statement itself).

Comment: Feb 29 is the date version of 1/0.

Comment: A general method here to clean data is to load it all into a generic load table with a bunch of text columns, and then find and fix / remove the bad rows. Then insert into the real table from the load table and drop the load table.

Answer (score 1):

## February has 28 days.

February in 2017 doesn't have 29 days. It has 28. End of story. If you need to store a 29th day, then your definition of `date` is different than PostgreSQL's and it will not be able to do date math or use date functions with *your* definition.

What is `'2017-02-29'::date + interval '1 day'` in your system though? February 30, March 1, or March 2? And, what would `'2017-02-29'::date + interval '1 day' - interval '1 day'` be?